# Put print result in a variable or concat text variable

Tags: macos, variables, terminal, zsh, concatenation

I have this

```
var1='hello'
var2='world'
```

I need `helloworld` in a variable. If I write

```
print $var1$var2              # prints "helloworld"
```

But when I write

```
var3=$var1$var2               # var3 is not "helloworld"
```

I tried

```
var3=$(print $var1$var2)
var3='$var1$var2'
```

Sure the only one I did not try is the good one but which one?

**Edit after discovery curious thing:**

If I do exactly as I wrote

```
var3=$var1$var2
print $var3                   # prints "helloworld"
```

But in fact I wrote this to resume my problem with others variables, my own variables. The difference is that `$var1` is the result of a `awk` command to extract this text from a file.

I try to explain:

`myvar1` the variable I realy use is definite like this:

`myvar1=awk -F"/" '${print $1}' $dir_path`

And not like this

`myvar1=world`

That is only to ask you the question. I don't know why, but this seems to be important.

If I do the same thing with my variables that with `var3=$var1$var2`, it doe snot work. To get the right result with my variables, I have just found I must use:

```
myvar3=echo$myvar1$myvar2
print $myvar3                 # gives the right result.
```

On the other hand, if I do

```
var3=echo$var1$var2
print $var3                   # prints "echohelloworld"
```

How to explain that?

I am using Mac OS X, the command-line terminal and Zsh.

Comment: nobody for an answer ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your initial claim is most likely wrong. Please click on the edit link and update/remove it accordingly. Furthermore I did not understand the `awk` part, can you please verify?

Comment: I edited my question to precise you what I mean about the awk part. Let me know if I'm clear enough

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
var1='hello'
var2='world'
```

Any of these will result in `print $var3      # prints "helloworld"`

```
var3="$var1$var2"
var4=$var1$var2
var5=$(print $var1$var2)
```

You should use the first one. You can verify either by printing the variables or by calling `set`:

```
$ print var3                                # prints "helloworld"

$ set|grep var
var1=hello
var2=world
var3=helloworld
var4=helloworld
var5=helloworld
```

Your edit says, that you use: `myvar1=awk -F"/" '{print $1} $dir_path`. This line is missing a `$()`:

```
myvar1=$(awk 'BEGIN { print "hello" }')
echo $myvar1                                # prints hello
```

Comment: You're right, I edited, this is: awk -F"/" '${Print $1}' $dir_path

Comment: The problem is print $var3 works well (with var1) but print $myvar3 doesn't (because myvar1 seems to be a different)

Comment: what is the output of `set|grep myvar1`?